# Spark custom output path after partition columns

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, is it possible to have suffix in the path after partition by columns?

For example:
I am write the data to the following path:
/db_name/table_name/dateid=20171009/event_type=TEST/

```
`dataset.write().partitionBy("event_type").save("/db_name/table_name/dateid=20171009");`
```

Is it possible to create it to the following with dynamic partition?
/db_name/table_name/dateid=20171009/event_type=TEST/1507764830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `newTaskTempFile` is the right place for this. The previous one doesn't work for dynamic partitions.

```
public String newTaskTempFile(TaskAttemptContext taskContext, Option<String> dir, String ext) {
    Option<String> dirWithTimestamp = Option.apply(dir.get() + "/" + timestamp)
    return super.newTaskTempFile(taskContext, dirWithTimestamp, ext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//sample json
{"event_type": "type_A", "dateid":"20171009", "data":"garbage" }
{"event_type": "type_B", "dateid":"20171008", "data":"garbage" }
{"event_type": "type_A", "dateid":"20171007", "data":"garbage" }
{"event_type": "type_B", "dateid":"20171006", "data":"garbage" }

// save as partition
spark.read
  .json("./data/sample.json")
  .write
  .partitionBy("dateid", "event_type").saveAsTable("sample")

//result
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @L.Li.

I was trying to have a timestamp after the partition columns like:
`/sample/dataid=20171006/event_type=type_b/1507764830`

Currently, I am doing it by add another column(_TS_) to the dataset, then partition by (dateid, event_type, _TS_), the output path is like:
`/sample/dataid=20171006/event_type=type_b/_TS_1507764830`

This make the "_TS_" a partition column if directly read from S3. That's the part I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code, the `FileOutputCommitter` is the way to do this.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local[2]")
            .config("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class", "com.estudio.spark.ESParquetOutputCommitter")
            .config("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "com.estudio.spark.ESSQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol")
            .getOrCreate();

ESSQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.realAppendMode = false;

spark.range(10000)
.withColumn("type", rand()    
.multiply(6).cast("int"))
.write()
.mode(Append)
.partitionBy("type")
.format("parquet")
.save("/tmp/spark/test1/");
```

Here is the customized `ParquetOutputCommitter`, it's the place to customize the output path. In this case, we're suffix the time-stamp. We have to make sure it's **synchronized**. Here is the code:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
public class ESParquetOutputCommitter extends ParquetOutputCommitter {

    private final static Map<String, Path> pathMap = new HashMap<>();

    public final static synchronized Path getNewPath(final Path path) {
        final String key = path.toString();
        log.debug("path.key: {}", key);

        if (pathMap.containsKey(key)) {
            return pathMap.get(key);
        }

        final Path newPath = new Path(path, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        pathMap.put(key, newPath);

        log.info("---> Path: {}, newPath: {}", path, newPath);
        return newPath;
    }

    public ESParquetOutputCommitter(Path outputPath, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
        super(getNewPath(outputPath), context);
        log.info("this: {}", this);
    }
}
```

We can also use the `getNewPath` method to get the customized path. Until now, this will work for `SaveMode.Overwrite`.

`SaveMode.Append` is little different, check out [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18621). So, for us to cover `Append` mode, we need to override `SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol` to always return the customized `ParquetOutputCommitter`. Here is the code:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputCommitter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol;
import org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

@Slf4j
public class ESSQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol extends SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol {

    public static boolean realAppendMode = false;

    private String jobId;
    private String path;
    private boolean isAppend;

    public ESSQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol(String jobId, String path, boolean isAppend) {
        super(jobId, path, isAppend);
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.path = path;
        this.isAppend = isAppend;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputCommitter setupCommitter(TaskAttemptContext context) {
        try {
            OutputCommitter committer = context.getOutputFormatClass().newInstance().getOutputCommitter(context);

            if (realAppendMode) {
                log.info("Using output committer class {}", committer.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                return committer;
            }

            final Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
            final String key = SQLConf.OUTPUT_COMMITTER_CLASS().key();

            final Class<? extends OutputCommitter> clazz;
            clazz = configuration.getClass(key , null, OutputCommitter.class);

            if (clazz == null) {
                log.info("Using output committer class {}", committer.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                return committer;
            }

            log.info("Using user defined output committer class {}", clazz.getCanonicalName());

            if (FileOutputCommitter.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                Constructor<? extends OutputCommitter> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Path.class, TaskAttemptContext.class);
                committer = ctor.newInstance(new Path(path), context);
            } else {
                Constructor<? extends OutputCommitter> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
                committer = ctor.newInstance();
            }

            return committer;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return super.setupCommitter(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Also added a static flag `realAppendMode` to turn all of this off.

Again, I am not Spark expert yet, let me know if ther
e is anything issue with this solution.